# How to install gnome-shell-extensions in Fedora 19?

Tags: fedora, gnome, yum, gnome3, repository

I want to install a GNOME extension into Fedora 19. I've been using this command:

```
$ yum install gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status
```

But it wasn't able to find the package. I tried adding this to the repository file, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
[fedora-gnome-shell-extensions]
name=Modify and extend GNOME Shell functionality and behavior
baseurl=http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/hien/gnome-shell-extensions/fedora-$releasever/$basearch/
enabled=1
skip_if_unavailable=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't be using that repository with Fedora 19. Those packages were built for Fedora 15.

*excerpt from the [repos page](http://repos.fedorapeople.org/)*

> gnome-shell-extensions    Modify and extend GNOME Shell functionality and behavior    hien    fedora-15

I found the RPM you're looking for here in the [Development repository](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/19/x86_64/os/Packages/g/), specifically here for the [gnome-shell-extension-alternative-status-menu package](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/19/x86_64/os/Packages/g/gnome-shell-extension-alternative-status-menu-3.8.3-2.fc19.noarch.rpm).

I do not have a F19 install to confirm this but I believe you need to either enable the "Development" repository or the "Update-Testing" repo.

A command like this would do it:

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable development
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable updates-testing
```

Comment: That repository _was_ the development tree for Fedora 19, but now that Fedora 19 is out, you can find it [release repository](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/19/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/), which means it will also be available for `yum install gnome-shell-extension-alternative-status-menu`

Answer (score 1):

The only problem here, I think, is that the package name has an extra word on the end, `-menu`, which is left out of your original command.

As @slm notes, you don't really want that repo file, since it's old and unmaintained. But, it appears that the package you want *is* in Fedora. Just do `yum install gnome-shell-extension-alternative-status-menu` and you should be all set.

Alternately, you can go to https://extensions.gnome.org/ and search for Alternative Status Menu, from which you will find [this page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5/alternative-status-menu/); there, click the on-off switch at the top left of the page and it will be downloaded into your own home directory (as opposed to installed system wide) and activated.